# What is the Correct context to use when the Application is closed/Not running. -

Tags: android

I have an app that receives push messages and stores a timestamp in a SharedPreference. When the App is quit i get a NPE caused by this:

```
SharedPreferences pref = MainActivity.mainActivity.getSharedPreferences("LAST_SYNC", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

It works fine when the app is running at the front or even in multitasking.  I'd appreciate some advice on how to handle processes when the app isn't running. Thanks

Code:

```
   // Store Push received time.
                    Log.d("eLOQ", "Updating last time synced");
                    DateFormat lastSyncFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
                    SharedPreferences pref = MainActivity.mainActivity.getSharedPreferences("LAST_SYNC", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = pref.edit();
                    ed.putString("LAST_SYNC_TIMESTAMP", lastSyncFormat.format(new Date()));
                    ed.apply();
```

Comment: Where is this exactly? In your `FirebaseMessagingService`? Can't you use `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: When you receive push message, your activity is not guaranteed to alive. So you should use application context to get the sharedPreference. I recommend you to use Dependency injection like dagger to deal with this. With dagger, you can define application modules and sharedPreference is good example which can be provided by application module. In short, don't use activity context from push message receiver and use application context. And DI framework is recommended.